# Cлайдер на React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, npm

Привет!Можете подсказать существуют ли уже готовые слайдеры для React JS которые можно поставить через npm или лучше самому сделать?

Comment: типо такого ? https://codepen.io/mburakerman/pen/LbBwWo

Comment: Именноо такой)С стрелочками и кружечками снизу.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю найдешь что нужно

- [React-Slick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick)
- [React-Image-Gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery)
- [React Responsive Carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel)

Comment: Оформите вопрос с ссылками

Answer (score 1):

Всегда интереснее делать самому) Но, если нужно готовое решение, то мне нравится вот этот: [react-slick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick) (23к скачиваний в день)

Comment: Спасибо,я также думаю может использовать от бутстрапа?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/